# Dynamic class name in PHP

Tags: php, dynamic, autoload

I'm trying to create a system that it has a GeneralObj. The GeneralObj allows user to initiate special objects for database's tables with a String of the table name. So far, it works perfect.

```
class GeneralObj{
    function __construct($tableName) {
        //...
    }
}
```

However, it is too tired to type new GeneralObj(XXX) every time.
I am wondering is that possible to simplify the process to like new XXX(), which is actually running the same as new GeneralObj(XXX)?
I spot PHP provided __autoload method for dynamic loading files in the setting include_path but it requires a the actually definition file existing. I really don't want to copy and copy the same definition files only changing a little.

For cause, eval is not an option.

Comment: Modify your autoloader - you are using an autoloader aren't you?

Comment: What is exactly the plan after you did this. Because I think its not a great idea to do it like this.

Comment: Shorten the name ... If you are too tired...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can just auto-create the files in the autoloader:

```
function __autoload($class_name) {
    // check for classes ending with 'Table'
    if (preg_match('/(.*?)Table/', $class_name, $match)) {
        $classPath = PATH_TO_TABLES . '/' . $match[1] . '.php';
        // auto-create the file
        if (!file_exists($classPath)) {
            $classContent = "
class $class_name extends GeneralObj {
    public __construct() {
        parent::__construct('{$match[1]}');
    }
}";
            file_put_contents($classPath, $classContent);
        }
        require_once $classPath;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question and the idea is good and should be able to work well. I would like to use this method to finish my task if there is no better solution. This autoloader is using a trick similar to the eval function, with a lot smaller number of disadvantage.

Comment: Sorry that, I am so new for stack overflow that I can't even vote your answer. Someone please help me to vote this guy.

Answer (score 1):

Use inheritance. Make GeneralObj the superclass of the table specific classes. This way you can dynamically derive class names and instantiate objects. Example:

```
class someTable extends GeneralObj {

}


$tableName = 'some';
$className = $tableName . 'Table';

$obj = new $className;
```

Comment: Problem is, I don't even want to use inheritance. the class definition is just annoying and doesn't make sense. It should not be necessary to  repeat the definition for only changing the name of table. In your example, we shill have to define classes as many as the tables in the database.

Comment: I get your point, but OO is about compromises... You write more code / create more classes for the sake of readability and maintainability. Modular design / pluggable components, etc. all best implemented using inheritance and other patterns.

Comment: In my opinion, OO should not be a golden rule. The reason that OO is so impotent is it separates the design and  program level and structurize the system. These features lets the outcoming code readable and manageable. However, today after OO developed  more than 50 years, OO lefts its purpose.

Comment: System applying OO becomes too structured. Even a small system should separated to tens of files, classes. It is horrible and skippable. Like the system I am working, it just a ORM system which should be easily port to an other database, which means it has no reason to hardly define any table object class. For these reason, Hibernate and EJB are failed product since its almost non-portable and really hard to use, even we have genetic tools to handle the heavy task.

Comment: The world needs dynamic. You may see a lot of supernova in programming language like Ruby, Python and super old man like Lisp are dynamic. It has no reason that they cannot build a big, useful system by well planning.

Comment: I also find dynamic solutions very useful sometimes. But, especially with PHP's magic methods, it often becomes more annoying than useful. Debugging becomes a nightmare. Your IDE stops providing clear relations, go to definition, etc, etc.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible.

The [runkit](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.runkit.php) extension allows programmatic manipulation of the PHP runtime environment, but it cannot do this. Even if it could, it would IMHO be a very bad idea, greatly impacting the requirements and complexity of the application in exchange for saving a few keystrokes.

In an unrelated note, your `GeneralObj` class has functionality that sounds suspiciously like that of a [dependency injection container](http://fabien.potencier.org/article/12/do-you-need-a-dependency-injection-container). Perhaps you should consider replacing it with one?

Comment: It is ORM system. I do not really understand dependency injection yet but it should be a kind of it. Hibernate and Entity Beans of EJB without config files are my finial goal. In this case, dynamic classes is needed, and it's the best solution I found so far.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this autoloader:

```
myAutoloader::Register();


class myAutoloader
{
    /**
     * Register the Autoloader with SPL
     *
     */
    public static function Register() {
        if (function_exists('__autoload')) {
            //  Register any existing autoloader function with SPL, so we don't get any clashes
            spl_autoload_register('__autoload');
        }
        //  Register ourselves with SPL
        return spl_autoload_register(array('myAutoloader', 'Load'));
    }   //  function Register()


    /**
     * Autoload a class identified by name
     *
     * @param   string  $pClassName     Name of the object to load
     */
    public static function Load($pClassName){
        if (class_exists($pClassName,FALSE)) {
            //  Already loaded
            return FALSE;
        }

        $pClassFilePath = str_replace('_',DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,$pClassName) . '.php';

        if (file_exists($pClassFilePath) === FALSE) {
            //  Not a class file
            return new GeneralObj($pClassName);
        }

        require($pClassFilePath);
    }   //  function Load()

}
```

And it's up to GeneralObj to throw an exception if the table class can't be instantiated

Comment: Is returning an instance from an autoload handler possible? I 've never seen it before, and the docs don't mention such a possibility.

Comment: Not sure, I've never actually tested it... I'll have a go now

Comment: Though the exception handling for invalid `table names` is a real pain in GeneralObj

Comment: Thank you rise up spl_autoload_register() which I never heard. But after some study on this group of api, I still cannot make it works. I have the same question as @Jon, it doesn't seem that autoload is excepted to return an instance. This is the testing program which trigger an error makes the program unable to finish as predicted [link](http://sharetext.org/UNaM)

Comment: If it is possible, please share which version of PHP you are using, it may help a lot. Mine is 5.2.6, is not the newest version some features may not work.

Comment: I know its a little unfair but ar... I still can't test it and not going to make this as an acceptable answer. But the idea is best of all. I am curious that why PHP hasn't this feature, at least not put it in the document. It should make a lot of fun.